# How to get the three key/value pairs with the lowest value from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object as below:

```js
var countryobj = {
    "Canada": 10,
    "Peru": 1,
    "Argentina": 5,
    "Colombia": 2,
    "Mexico": 8
};
```

I want to get the first 3 smallest key value pair so that my output would be:

```
Peru: 1
Colombia: 2
Argentina: 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros no, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the `Object.entries` and sort them based on their value in ascending order, then print the first three items formatted how you like.

```js
var countryobj = {
 "Canada": 10,
 "Peru": 1,
 "Argentina": 5,
 "Colombia": 2,
 "Mexico": 8
};

const entries = Object.entries(countryobj).sort(([, a], [, b]) => a - b);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(entries[i][0] + ": " + entries[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRange(obj, count) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([, prev], [, next]) => a - b)
    .slice(0, count)
    .reduce(
      (result, [key]) => ({
        ...result,
        [key]: obj[key],
      }),
    {},
  );
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this by rebuilding the object using: `return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort(...).slice(...))`